# Slack: Red dot only for personal notifications

Tags: slack

Slack's little red dot is useful for telling you when you have unread messages, or people directly mention you with @yourname.  But unfortunately it also shows up when people use @here or @channel - which quickly leads to you ignoring messages and missing ones that actually matter.

Is there some way to keep having the red dot for personal messages, but to lose it for inane @here and @channel mentions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://slack.com/help/articles/201355156-Guide-to-desktop-notifications) describes how to change your notification preferences for a channel.

1. Open the channel or group DM.
2. Click the  gear icon to open the Channel or Conversation settings menu.
3. Select Notification preferences.
4. Choose your notification preferences, and whether you'd like to use different settings for mobile devices.
5. Click the  close icon in the top right to save and exit.